# Check if a DIV exist before running some Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem, on a blog I have this javascript code below that is used to get the Position of a DIV id `author-info`.  The problem is this div is only on actual article pages and not on any of the directory pages or the index.

So on these pages that do not have the div I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
```

And here is the javascript causing the error

```
var commentsPos = $('#author-info').offset().top - $(window).height();
```

I know I could do this in the backend to only show that line of JS on the proper pages but I would like to avoid that as this is just 1 line of a much bigger javascript file that is included into the page.

What are my options here?  Any help please, I assume I need to somehow check to see if this div exist on the page before calling this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the DOM element exists and then do your jQuery

```
if( document.getElementById('author-info') != null )
{
 var commentsPos = $('#author-info').offset().top - $(window).height();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $authInfo = $('#author-info');

if($authInfo.length > 0){
    var commentsPos = $authInfo.offset().top - $(window).height();
}
```

Comment: @davidthomas Seriously...?  Include jquery first.  jQuery ALWAYS returns an object.  I'm going to attribute this to a mental slip... you **have** to know that...